# How to convert local db to new version?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have GAE SDK 1.5.1 and want to upgrade it to 1.5.5. Unfortunately my old db which is used in SDK 1.5.1 is not being loaded in new SDK 1.5.5. I use following arguments to run local server:

`dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=../var/mydb.db --skip_sdk_update_check .`

Why it's not loading, and how do I use the existed db in SDK 1.5.5?

Comment: There is no error message, just showing empty models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the bulkloader to download the contents of the DB using the old SDK, and upload them to the SDK.

By far the best option, however, is to set up your development environment so you have a set of test data that's easily loaded and reloaded. The dev_appserver's local stub is *not* designed to act as a permanent datastore, and you should be able to recreate your test data easily.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to include `--default_partition=` - see here for details:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-appengine/kJGPWT4fhgw/discussion